# Reducing a 'raw' javascript array into a more compact array (of objects)

Tags: javascript, arrays, functional-programming

In javascript, I'm looking for a tidy way of processing an array such that the **short, repeating sequences** (tuples) in a collection become reduced into a **more compact collection**. I want to convert an array of length *3n* to a collection of length *n*.

Here's an imaginary example:

```
// A flat (1-dimensional) array of numbers for input
var input = [ 
  1, 11, 5,
  2, 12, 10,
  3, 13, 6,
  4, 14, 11,   
  ... ];

// A custom "lambda". This is my main intent, the rest is just plumbing.
var formatData = function(a,b,c) {
  return { foo: a, bar: b, woot: c };
};

var output = input.reduceMulti(3, formatData); // ficticious 'reduceMulti'!

// output: 
// [
//   { foo: 1, bar: 11, woot: 5  },
//   { foo: 2, bar: 12, woot: 10 },
//   { foo: 3, bar: 13, woot: 6  },
//   { foo: 4, bar: 14, woot: 11 },
//   ...
// ]
```

Alternatively, those objects in `output` could easily be strings, or arrays, if `formatData` returned something different.

I'm looking for a solution a lot like `reduce`, except with the ability to reduce to more than a single value.

Bonus points for being performant, but ultimately the solution should be readable, maintainable, and usable.

Comment: did you intend to make the `input` variable a list of lists or is the existing assignment right?

Comment: @Hrishi The `input` array is just a simple 1-dimensional array, formatted to make the groups of three clearer. (It is correct as is.)

Comment: Which do you want more... native Array functions or speed? A `for` loop is usually much faster.

Comment: @squint Keen on speed, but not at the cost of readability and functional usability. (Sometimes the two can even intersect!) Native functions not necessary: use your judgement.

Comment: you want to use map() on the main array (to trasnform each), and reduce on the sub-arrays (to summarize each).

Comment: @dandavis post an answer!

Answer (score 3):

You can still use `reduce` which takes also an index and the array as arguments:

```
var formatData = function(x, y, z) {
  return [x, y, z]
}

var reduceMulti = function(n, f, xs) {
  return xs.reduce(function(acc, x, i, xs) {
    if (i % n === 0) {
      acc.push(f.apply(null, xs.slice(i, i+n)))
    }
    return acc
  },[])
}

reduceMulti(3, formatData, input)
//^ [[1,11,5], [2,12,10], [3,13,6], [4,14,11]]
```

If you give `n` a value of `3` then you'd have to pass a function that expects 3 arguments.

Comment: Nice! Great to see the native reduce function used to solve this. It's a shame you can't skip over the "return acc" calls.

Comment: If I give this an array whose number of elements is not an exact multiple of `n`, then it gives me back undefineds at the end of the last partition. It would also not work for other partition sizes. This could be solved by changing `formatData` to simply return `arguments`. From a design perspective, I'm also not convinced that combining the notion of a partition with a notion of somehow transforming (via `formatData`) the elements in each partition, is ideal. It would seem better to have a stand-alone partitioner, and then let the user do whatever he wants with the partitions.

Answer (score 2):

I would start off with a simple little routine to partition an array into segments of equal size:

```
function partition(arr, n) {
    return arr.length ? [arr.splice(0, n)].concat(partition(arr, n)) : [];
}
```

And a little sum function:

```
function sum(arr) { return arr.reduce(function(s, v) { return s + v; }); }
```

Now, we'll partition the original array and map it to the objects of statistical measures:

```
partition(input, 3).map(function(seg) {
    return {
        max:  Math.max.apply(0, seg), 
        min:  Math.min.apply(0, seg), 
        mean: sum(seg)/seg.length};
    };
})
```

If you would prefer a non-recursive segmenter:

```
function partition(arr, n) {
    var result = [];
    while (arr.length) { result.push(arr.splice(0, n)); }
    return result;
}
```

This takes advantage of the behavior of `Array#splice`, that it modifies the array to remove the specified elements and returns an array of the removed elements.

If you really want to achieve exactly the syntax you propose, then you would need to put `reduceMulti` on the Array prototype, not that I'm recommending that:

```
Array.prototype.reduceMulti = function(n, reducer) {
    return partition(this, n).map(reducer);
}

var output = input.reduceMulti(3, formatData);
```

Comment: Oh wow, recursive partition function! Since there's no tail recursion in any browser I know, is there a danger that for large datasets you'd get a ... _stack overflow_?

Comment: @aaaidan Not only recursive and prone to stack overflows, but also destructive--your array magically becomes empty!

Comment: Wow, great sell dude!

Answer (score 1):

Break the problem into steps: group the flat array, use `map()` to transform each one, and `reduce` to calc the sum.

```
var r= [ 
  1, 11, 5,
  2, 12, 10,
  3, 13, 6,
  4, 14, 11,
 ];

function flatToGrouped(r, width){
  var o=[];
  for(var i=0, mx=r.length; i<mx; i+=width){
   o.push(r.slice(i, i+width) );
  }
  return o.filter(Boolean);
}

function report(a,_,__){
  return { 
    min:  Math.min.apply(0,a), 
    max:  Math.max.apply(0,a), 
    mean: a.reduce( function(a,b,_,__){ return a+b; } ) 
  }
}

flatToGrouped(r, 3).map(report);
```

The extra formal parameters look weird, but they make the function run faster than they other wise would (i just found out arity matching improves optimization - i'm telling everyone).

EDIT: i didn't realize the initial array was flat. you can still use the simple map on the item transformer, and use a collector to make the n-level array you want to analyze. by breaking them into two parts, you're not locked into a reduce, but rather anything an array can do (map/reduce/filter/etc).

Comment: The initial array is flat.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but calculating the min, max, mean, isn't what I'm trying to achieve. Read the question again, and let me know how you think I could make it clearer.

Comment: @aaaidan: i edited... the logic is hot-swappable, just pass a different function to map() instead of report(); you don't need to build anything ahead of time if you use interchangeable generic parts...

Comment: @dandavis That sounds reasonable, but forgive me, I'm a little confused by your use of `Math.min`/`max` and `reduce` in the report function. They had led me to believe you think I want to perform those operations, so I've edited the question. Awesomely, `flatToGrouped` looks very promising, I'll have a look at that now.

Comment: @aaaidan: yeah, i just filled-in some logic, but it's a weed among trees.

Comment: @dandavis Ah, I getcha, `flatToGrouped` is the main part of the answer, that's great! I like that swiss army knife philosophy, thanks for the awesome work.

Comment: @dandavis I just formatted your code so I could grok it a bit easier. Why is it that you use `call` on an empty array's `push` function with `o` as the `this`, rather than just calling it directly on `o`?

Comment: Also, could you elaborate on the arity matching optimisation? (Or provide a link)?

Comment: @aaaidan: because it was late and i was tired ;) you can see the diff with arity matching on most of the tests in http://danml.com/mofun/#Performance, comparing van___Anon to van___AnonArity. the bonus is about 10-20%, not as much as i thought, but worth cheap and easy.

Comment: @dandavis When I check the map performance it's about a 1% boost... :/